# How can i change from Ldap to Ldaps

Tags: php, ldap

I have a functioning code that creats an Ldap connection to an online test server.

```
<?php

$ldap_dn = "uid=".$_POST["username"].",dc=example,dc=com";
$ldap_password = $_POST["password"];

$ldap_con = ldap_connect("ldap.forumsys.com");
ldap_set_option($ldap_con, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

if(@ldap_bind($ldap_con,$ldap_dn,$ldap_password))
    {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST["username"];

    header("Location: Startseite.php");

    }

else
    {
    echo "Invalid Credential";
    }
?>
```

Now i want to change the code to connect to a local Windows server and retrieve data from the active directory.
This connection should be an Ldaps.
Here is the code i tried.

```
<?php

$ldap_dn = "uid=".$_POST["username"].",dc=ULTIMATE,dc=local";
$ldap_password = $_POST["password"];

$ldap_con = ldap_connect("ldaps://192.168.***.**:636,OU=ULTIMATE,DC=ultimate,DC=local");
ldap_set_option($ldap_con, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

if(@ldap_bind($ldap_con,$ldap_dn,$ldap_password))
    {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST["username"];

    header("Location: Startseite.php");

    }

else
    {
    echo "Invalid Credential";
    }
?>
```

And i get the following error

Warning: ldap_connect(): Could not create session handle: Bad parameter to an ldap routine in C:\xampp\htdocs\Kulinarik\ldap.php on line 10

Why is it a bad parameter ?

**EDIT**

So the Active directory is Passwort protected and the users who want to start the query have no rights.
So i would have to make a Bind with the Credentials of the Sysadmin and then make a query inside the active directory with the Credentials of the users.

Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
$ldap_con = ldap_connect("ldaps://192.168.***.**:636");
```

> Without `,OU=ULTIMATE,DC=ultimate,DC=local` part.

Comment: $ldap_dn = $_POST["username"].",OU=EUTM,OU=Users,OU=HQ,OU=ULTIMATE,DC=ultimate,DC=local";

du you know if the username has to stand in front or on the back

Comment: @Etzi138 I think, it's normally at front like: ```$ldap_dn = 'cn=' .  $_POST["username"];```

Comment: I made an edit maybe you know the answer to this question to ?